# Changing foreground color of certain string in a label

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I would like to know if it is possible to change the foreground color of the string `item.Name` in the following coding, while the rest of the string stays the default color that I set in the label's foreground color setting in XAML.

```
lblLoggedInUser.Content = "Logged in:  " + item.Name + " " + item.Surname;
```

I would like `item.Name` to have a diffirent color than the rest of the string. IS that possible?

Comment: Have you tried using a StackPanel with Labels containing different Foreground attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a helper class with attached properties for this purpose.

```
public class HighlightHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static Brush GetHighlightBrush(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Brush)obj.GetValue(HighlightBrushProperty);
    }
    public static void SetHighlightBrush(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HighlightBrushProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HighlightBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(HighlightHelper), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));

    public static string GetHighlightWord(UIElement element)
    {
        return (string)element.GetValue(HighlightWordProperty);
    }
    public static void SetHighlightWord(UIElement element, string value)
    {
        element.SetValue(HighlightWordProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightWordProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HighlightWord", typeof(string), typeof(HighlightHelper), new PropertyMetadata(OnHighlightWordChanged));

    private static void OnHighlightWordChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock textBlock = (TextBlock)d;
        string text = textBlock.Text;
        string highlightWord = (string)e.NewValue;

        textBlock.Inlines.Clear();

        string[] tokens = Regex.Split(text, "(" + Regex.Escape(highlightWord) + ")");

        foreach (string token in tokens)
        {
            Run run = new Run { Text = token };

            if (token.Equals(highlightWord))
            {
                Brush highlightBrush = (Brush)textBlock.GetValue(HighlightBrushProperty);
                run.Foreground = highlightBrush;
            }

            textBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}" Foreground="Red"
            local:HighlightHelper.HighlightWord="{Binding TextToHighlight}"
            local:HighlightHelper.HighlightBrush="Blue"></TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to do this would be to use a horizontal `StackPanel` containing `Label`s with the `Foreground` attribute set to different colours. For example:

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#000000">Logged in: </Label>
    <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="#FFFFFF"></Label>
  </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="Logged in" />
        <Run Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Blue" />
        <Run Text="{Binding Surname}" />
    </TextBlock>
```